# Shiro Intermittent Subject.getPrincipal

Tags: java-ee-6, shiro

I've created a JavaEE6 project and currently I'm using Shiro for authentication and authorization. Using this article as a reference ([Using Shiro for Authorization via CDI Interceptors then Easily Test with Arquillian](http://spring-java-ee.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-shiro-for-authorization-via-cdi.html)), I've integrated Shiro with CDI. Everything works fine except for sometimes Subject.getPrincipal is null.

Further, investigations shows that sometimes I have at least 2 Subject.getSession().getId().

How I encounter the problem:

1. Login -> ok with sessionA
2. Click a link that is secured (pageA) -> ok
3. Tried to insert a record in the database that failed
4. Click the same secured link (pageA) -> failed, looking at the trace it produced a different session id sessionB
5. Refresh and refresh until page (pageA) is ok. Got the same session id during login sessionA.

What could be wrong?

My shiro.ini file

```
[main]
saltedJdbcRealm=com.sido.commons.web.security.shiro.JdbcRealmImpl

# any object property is automatically configurable in Shiro.ini file
saltedJdbcRealm.jndiDataSourceName=Portal 

# the realm should handle also authorization
saltedJdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled=true

# If not filled, subclasses of JdbcRealm assume "select password from users where username = ?"
# first result column is password, second result column is salt 
saltedJdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password, salt FROM users WHERE username = ?

# If not filled, subclasses of JdbcRealm assume "select role_name from user_roles where username = ?"
saltedJdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT name FROM roles a INNER JOIN user_roles b ON a.id=b.role_id INNER JOIN users c ON c.id=b.user_id WHERE c.username = ?

# If not filled, subclasses of JdbcRealm assume "select permission from roles_permissions where role_name = ?"
saltedJdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT action FROM permissions WHERE role = ?

# password hashing specification, put something big for hasIterations
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
sha256Matcher.hashIterations=1
saltedJdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO 

cacheManager=org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager 
cacheManager.cacheManagerConfigFile=classpath:shiro-ehcache.xml
securityManager.cacheManager=$cacheManager 

shiro.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout = logout
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>south-street</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SecurityProducer, a Singleton bean where I instantiate the security manager. It should be available and unique to the entire application right?

```
@Singleton
public class SecurityProducer {
    @Inject
    private Logger log;
    private SecurityManager securityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final String iniFile = "classpath:shiro.ini";
        log.debug("Initializing Shiro INI SecurityManager using " + iniFile);
        securityManager = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(iniFile).getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    }
    ..
}
```

Binding the SecurityManager nor Subject on initialization (Singleton bean) doesn't fixed the problem.

```
final String iniFile = "classpath:shiro.ini";
securityManager = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(iniFile).getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
ThreadContext.bind(SecurityUtils.getSubject()); or ThreadContext.bind(securityManager);
```

Thanks,

czetsuya

Comment: Whar does your web.xml  look like?

Comment: Hi jbunting, I've updated my post with the web.xml. Note that I did not add any shiro tags in web.xml because I initialized the security manager in a Singleton bean. But I noticed that I'm having at least 2 sessions with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved the intermittent session issue by configuring the web.xml base here: http://shiro.apache.org/web.html.

Currently here's how it looks:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

```
<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But is that really the solution? Any ideas?

Comment: It's been almost 3 years, and I think I have a similar problem today =)... Any new insights ?

Comment: Hi, did you have the same configuration as the web.xml above? That's solved my issue if I remember correctly. You might also want to check BalusC's article about Shiro, just google it.

Comment: The webl.xml is fine, and I mistaken my issue here, nothing to see with yours. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build subject manually you should bind it to the thread calling  `ThreadContext.bind(subject)`. If you don't do this the next calling `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` will return the new Subject not one that you've created before.

For example in my application i received session id in request and create a subject from it.

```
Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject();
ThreadContext.bind(subject);
```

Comment: Hi m1st.kh, I've initialized the security manager in a Singleton bean so that means I should have a single instance of it in the entire application right? I'm wondering why I'm having at least 2 sessions when I tried subject.getPrincipal().getSession().getId(). Regarding your suggestion, is it applicable ThreadContext.bind(subject) to a javaee6 app? Thanks.

Comment: As your suggestion, I tried binding the SecurityManager and the Subject when I initialized in the Singleton Bean, but it failed. See my post edited above. Still sometimes SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal() return null and I can see a different session id. Also note that I'm not building the subject manually.